# Why did my job get stuck while trying local Gitlab-runner?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I got this

[image]

[image]
Runner has never contacted this instance,what does it mean?

I can confirm that I have one.

Available specific runners

[image]

My .gitlab-ci.yml

```
stages:
    - build_stage
    - deploy_stage

build:
    stage: build_stage
    script:
        - docker --version
        - docker build -t pyapp .
    tags:
        - localshell
        - localrunner

deploy:
    stage: deploy_stage
    script:
        - docker stop pyappcontainer1 || true && docker rm pyappcontainer1 || true
        - docker run -d --name pyappcontainer1 -p 8080:8080 pyapp
    tags:
        - localshell
        - localrunner
```

Just to add this,to confirm what sytech said
Runtime platform                                    arch=amd64

```
os=linux pid=4819 revision=bd40e3da version=14.9.1
Starting multi-runner from /etc/gitlab-runner/config.toml...  builds=0
Running in system-mode.                            
                                                   
Configuration loaded                                builds=0
listen_address not defined, metrics & debug endpoints disabled  builds=0
[session_server].listen_address not defined, session endpoints disabled  builds=0
```

How to define listen_address?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In some cases, it solved bu running `gitlab-runner verify`.

So, just run it...

Comment: The [verify command](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/commands/#gitlab-runner-verify) is only an informative check to see if the runners are registered. It will not take any corrective action. You can also confirm in the [source code for the command](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/-/blob/ce628b741cc4b9ae845741e4279a6c64577d88d4/commands/verify.go) it won't take any action except potentially deleting unregistered runners if you pass the `--delete` flag.

Answer (score 1):

Your runner is *registered*, but is not running and communicating with GitLab to pick up jobs. Hence, jobs depending on this runner are stuck.

You should make sure the `gitlab-runner` process is actively running and there are no errors in its logs.

Comment: Take a look at my edit. How should I edit my config.toml?

Comment: listen_address does not need to be defined -- that's for the metrics server. Be sure your runner is now "online" in the GitLab UI and that the runner is enabled for the project @RichardRublev .